"array method" con javascript
me gustaria saber porque tengo que usar PUNTO MAP para que el codigo funcione


const existe = arr.some((curso) => curso.id === cursoInfo.id);
if (existe) {
  arr.map((curso) => {
    if (curso.id === cursoInfo.id) {
      curso.cantidad++;
      return curso;
    } else {
      return curso;
    }
  });
} else {
  arr = [...arr, cursoInfo];
}




Tu pregunta no tiene sentido. Usar some no implica usar map a continuación. Al contrario... si usas some no deberías encadenar un map, pues some devuelve un único valor booleano, true o false. Si añadieses el código que estás usando exactamente podríamos saber por qué afirmas que eso es necesario, cuando no lo es en absoluto. Estás reasignando tu array al valor devuelto por some?? De todas maneras, usa el enlace [edit] para añadir el código relevante para reproducir tu problema, si no es imposible saber qué estás haciendo. Y some tampoco se usa para saber si un elemento existe...
